# Writing to new .txt file with Excel VBA macro, code snippet won't compile (Expected =)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write an Excel macro that loops through cells (4 columns, some # of rows) and writes the contents to a text file with each cell separated by a carriage return. I'm getting a compile error "= expected" with creating the text file:

```
Dim filePath As String
filePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
If Not System.IO.file.Exists(filePath) Then
    System.IO.file.Create(filePath).Dispose()
End If
```

Full code:

```
Sub GenerateFile()
    'get last row with data
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    lastRow = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

    'loop through rows to build string
    Dim textFile As String
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        textFile = textFile & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1) & Chr(13) & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2) & Chr(13) & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3) & Chr(13) & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4) & Chr(13)
    Next i

    'write string to file
    Dim filePath As String
    filePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    If Not System.IO.file.Exists(filePath) Then
        System.IO.file.Create(filePath).Dispose()
    End If
End Sub
```

[EDIT] So I think it may be because I was trying to use a VB code snippet, I've found a guide here(http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s211/writeline.htm) to use FileSystemObject and TextStream but these require enabling of a library. I need to share this tool with others and cannot ask them all to enable the library :( Any other suggestions?

Comment: `System.IO.file.Create()` returns a file stream.  I'm not sure you can or should attempt to dispose it in the same line.  You need to use that File Stream to put data into your file.

Comment: Are you using VB.Net in visual studio or VBA in Excel. Your title mentions a VBA macro, but the code that is creating the text file is VB.Net (which would probably not compile in VBA).

Comment: If I remove the .Dispose() , I then still get a 424 Object Required error.

Comment: Sorry for the double comment, new to stackoverflow. I am using VBA in excel, did not realize it was different.

Comment: @SophieChen break the line into two.  You have no actual code to write data to the file.  Need to use the File Stream created by `Create()` to put data into your file.  Then call `Dispose()' on the File Stream

Comment: @jradich I then get a 424 Object Required error, but I think it is because the code is for VB.Net but I am using VBA. Looking for an alternative code snippet that will work for VBA without needing to enable a library.

Comment: @Blackwood Thanks I found some resources indicating to use TextStream and FileSystemObject  but to use FSO I need to enable the library; this spreadsheet needs to be shared with others so I cannot ask them all to enable this library also.

Comment: @SophieChen If the reference is included in the project and you send someone who has Excel a copy of the file, they don't need to put the reference in themselves. In any event -- you can use late binding to bypass the need for external library references.

Comment: @JohnColeman I'm not knowledgeable of how to use late binding, but that is great news! I'm enabled the library reference and the tool works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @SophieChen See this: http://www.jpsoftwaretech.com/vba/filesystemobject-vba-examples/ for how to use late bindings for FSO

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like the following would work in VBA with out having to add references

```
Dim filePath As String
filePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

Open filePath + "\Output.txt" For Output As #1

For Row = 1 To 100
    For Column = 1 To 100
        Write #1, ws.Cells(Row, Column).Value
    Next Column
Next Row

Close #1
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered thanks to http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s211/writeline.htm and @JohnColeman:

Used this below code and enabled reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime' library (Tools>References> 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime')

```
'get filePath, fileName
Dim filePath As String
filePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
fileName = "\file.txt"

'create file
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim ts As TextStream
Set ts = fso.CreateTextFile(filePath & fileName, True)
ts.WriteLine (fileString)
ts.Close
```